# Ionic, The pipe 'translate' could not be found, only in AoT Compiler

Tags: ionic-framework, ngx-translate

I have a problem with ngx-translate within a Ionic App when I try to build a production release.

During development translations work fine with

```
ionic serve
```

and

```
ionic cordova build android
```

but if I try to make a production build using

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

or for the PWA

```
ionic build --prod
```

I get some errors like

```
[17:47:15]  typescript error 
            The pipe 'translate' could not be found ( ... )
```

Versions:

- ngx-translate: 8.0.0
- Ionic: 3.9.2
- Angular: 5.2.10

I checked with: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/tree/v8.0.0 and can't find what I am doing wrong.

In app.module:

```
// https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#1-import-the-translatemodule
// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader( http, './assets/i18n/', '.json' );
} 

@NgModule( {
    ...
    imports: [
        ...
        TranslateModule.forRoot( {
                loader: {
                    provide: TranslateLoader,
                    useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
                    deps: [ Http ]
                }
            }
        ),
        ...
```

And in one of my pages which produce this error:

```
import {  TranslateModule, TranslateService, TranslatePipe } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        TranslateModule
    ],
    exports: [
        TranslateModule
    ]
})
export class ContactPage { ... }
```

Searching through SO produced mainly the hint to import & export the TranslateModule in the page as well as importing the TranslatePipe, but both of these changes didn't solve my problem. How do I configure the translation module so that it works in a production build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, solved it. I added the import & export statement of the TranslateModule to the page class, but correct is to add it the the corresponding module.

In my example:

Wrong:

contact.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        TranslateModule
    ],
    exports: [
        TranslateModule
    ]
})
export class ContactsPage {...}
```

Correct:

contact.module.ts

```
@NgModule( {
    ...
    imports : [
        ...
        TranslateModule
    ],
    exports : [
        TranslateModule
    ]

} )
export class ContactsPageModule {
}
```